# Use of can't/cannot to indicate the opposite

Tags: american-english, colloquialisms

I cannot find any references online that would help me know what this topic in English grammar is called, but I'm trying to guide a non-American friend to understand why some would use the word "can't" or "cannot" to imply the opposite, as in

"I will see if I can't get to the bottom of this for you."

Of course it is clearer to say "I will see if I can get to the bottom of this for you," however, I suspect the former is not technically incorrect grammar, though it certainly may be a localized expression. At any rate, it is definitely a common occurrence.

However, being as that I don't know what this usage of "can't" to imply the opposite is called and that it's ridiculously hard to Google, I can't seem to find out either way if it's right or wrong.

EDIT

Thinking over this some more, I feel that the sentence using "can't" is actually clearer than the one with "can." I'm thinking that using "can't" in this case implies the difficulty/perplexity of the situation, and makes it clear that I'll be trying hard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idiom seems to be something like **Vᵖ *if/whether* S/¬S**, where

- **Vᵖ** refers to some mental Perception verb (*see, discover, figure out,* ...) that can take
- **S** is an Embedded Question complement from a *Yes/No* Question. These use *whether* or *if* as a complementizer (*Can/Did they do it*? ==> *whether/if they can do it/did it*).

**Either** S or ¬S can occur in the complement; i.e, *if they can do it* vs *if they can't do it*. This is because it eventually occurs to everybody that, if you can discover that X **will** occur, then you also know if X **won't** occur, and vice versa. *Yes/No* questions are binary, so an answer to either one gives you the same information.  (p ⊃ q) ≡ (¬p ∨ q).

I don't know whether a modal is strictly necessary in the S, though of course modals like *will* and *can* do occur very frequently with hypotheticals like *if*, and interact strongly with negatives. See the many Language Log postings on ["Overnegation"](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/index.php?s=overnegation).

Comment: Thank you; it comes naturally. I always used to make my syntax courses start with an [introduction to logic](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf). One doesn't really have to learn much logic, but knowing a little about propositions gives a novel [perspective on sentences](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/VPguide.pdf) to many students.

Comment: Thanks. I'm a computer engineer, so this answer went straight to the heart, what with the logical complements and all  :)

Comment: I'm using _complement_ in a special sense that means _Noun Clause functioning as Subject or Object_, not the logical sense. See [here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/complmnt.html).

Answer (score 1):

*I will see if I can't . . .* and *I will see if I can . . .* are both grammatical, and both sentences can be used to make an offer. The difference lies in their use. The negative form is more colloquial and is slightly more forthcoming than the positive form, which is more likely to be followed by *. . . but I can’t promise anything.* I know of no name for this construction, although there might a Greek word for it somewhere in a list of tropes.

Comment: That's pretty much my initial opinion as well, but I find it hard to believe that there isn't a more authoritative answer about somewhere that I can point my friend to. I've checked the index of LBH, but it isn't helping much.